# Function restriction with Libertinus Math

Tags: symbols, libertine

The following code raises an error because `\restriction` is not defined (and neither is `\upharpoonright`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\begin{document}
$f \restriction A$
\end{document}
```

I understand that it is not wise to use `amssymb` in this case.  Is there a recommended way to get a function restriction symbol nevertheless?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly the `libertinust1math` fonts do not include that particular harpoon. Sebastiano has shown how to import it from the `AMSa` symbols. I propose here two further alternatives:

Instead of `libertinust1math` you can use `newtxmath` with the `libertine` option. This will use the Latin and Greek letters from `libertine` but otherwise the symbols from `newtx`, which contain more glyphs than `libertinust1math`. Of course, the output will change, so it's a matter of taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$f \restriction A$
$\scriptstyle f \restriction A$
$\scriptscriptstyle f \restriction A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can rotate `\leftharpoonup`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\upharpoonright}{\mathrel{\mkern-2mu\mathpalette\@upharpoonright\relax}}
\newcommand*{\@upharpoonright}[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{\rotatebox{-90}{$#1\leftharpoonup$}}}}
\makeatother
\let\restriction\upharpoonright

\begin{document}
$f \restriction A$
$\scriptstyle f \restriction A$
$\scriptscriptstyle f \restriction A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 to you for the comment and the answer. The same to @Davislor. THANKS.

Answer (score 7):

The OpenType version of Libertinus Math has ↾ (U+21BE), and `unicode-math` supports it as `\upharpoonright`.  Output with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus} % Load the OpenType fonts

\newcommand\restriction\upharpoonright

\begin{document}
$f \restriction A_{f \restriction A_{f \restriction A}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus Math sample]

Answer (score 6):

Looking in [website](http://labmaster.mi.infn.it/wwwasdoc.web.cern.ch/wwwasdoc/TL8/texmf/doc/latex/base/html/fntguide/node18.html) you can declare or use one symbol. Hence
it is very important to know the number of the slot `{"16}` for `\upharpoonright` symbol.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upharpoonright}{\mathrel}{AMSa}{"16}
```

Using this MWE, for example, with `\usepackage{amssymb}` you have,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\begin{document}
$f \restriction A$
\end{document}
```

and you will have this output:

[image]

Or you can use this MWE without the use of `amssymb` package that have the same output of the previous image.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSa}{U}{msa}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upharpoonright}{\mathrel}{AMSa}{"16}
\global\let\restriction\upharpoonright
\begin{document}
$f \restriction A$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your second code has the advantage that it uses up only one math family. But I had already upvoted...

Comment: @campa ahahahahahaha :-)...there is not problem...To me I like to know :-)))))))